# How can I enable WebCL in my browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, opencl

I have experience with WebGL in javascript and with (py)OpenCL and both are great tools. Now I would like to put it together and do fast science/engineering demos in web browser. But I'm not sure if the technology is mature and supported by contemporary web-browsers?

There are two web pages with demos:

- http://toaarnio.github.io/webcl-test-suite/
- http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webcl/webcl.htm

but I cannot run any example neither in Firefox nor in Chrome. Firefox asks to install WebCL with message: `This page requires Nokia WebCL for Firefox. Install?` but after I install it and restart Firefox, it still does not work. I get always message: `Unfortunately your system does not support WebCL`

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and nVidia GTX960M ... and I'm able to compile and run OpenCL programs in C++ and in python.

---

Besides making it work on my computer, I'm also interested to make sure other people will be able to see my physics web demos in their browser. For WebGL the support is already quite good ... I hope it is just matter of time when the same will be true for WebCL - am I right ?

Comment: What kind of answer to you expect? The support isn't currently there and it might turn either way. As an example the [Wiki article on WebCL states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebCL) `Mozilla does not plan to implement WebCL in favor of OpenGL ES 3.1 Compute Shaders.`. Which doesn't mean they can't change their stance. As for your error you will have to provide more information.

Comment: actually the answer "it is normal that it does not work yet" is fine. I just want to know if I do something wrong or if I should just wait until it is implemented. ... I mean: How can I know without asking? The browser only throws at me an error message, it does not say if it is normal behavior or it is just me being stupid or having some wrong/old/not-up-to-data driver/browser.

Comment: add `Mozilla does not plan to implement WebCL in favor of OpenGL ES 3.1 Compute Shaders.` ...great! are they supported  already ?

Comment: You're actually asking two questions. Hence my first remark. The first is about an error you're getting with your installation. Which probably should work and might just have some configuration issue. The second is whenever the technology as a whole will be adapted and is step in the right direction. While the first part probably can be analyzed and answered the latter would be a guessing game and a matter of opinions. OpenGL ES would probably require [WebGL which is based on OpenGL ES 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).